# How to left-align particular equations using own environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm trying to left align particular equations. To do that I created a new environment (because I need it a few times).

Now, I found that there are various options to do that:

- using the `fleqn` option - but that does a left alignment for all the equations in the document
- `flalign` - but for that I always have to write `&&` at the end and it doesn't seem to work in an environment I defined

I would like to be able to use for this kind of special equations some code like this

```
\begin{leftalignedequation}
...
\end{leftalignedequation}
```

and it should do all the magic itself.

And so my question is: What would you see as the best way to achieve that? I don't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: I think you need to also adjust the value of `\mathindent`. Setting that to `0pt` should left align to the margin.

Comment: The package `nccmath` offers this. But I'd advise against doing it. First ask yourself why you should do it.

Comment: But `mathindent` does so for the whole document, right? @egreg I will have a look at `nccmath`, thanks. I know, and I think you are right in asking whether it's really necessary. The document is about defining a relational algebra (for databases) and I mix a more mathematic and more computer science view and the latter I would like to align left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle the left aligning of equations via `\@fleqntrue` and `\@fleqnfalse`.  Changing `\@mathindent` will change how much they are offset from the left margin.  Perhaps the simplest way is to turn this on off for parts of a document by defining a new environment `fleqns`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fleqns}[1][0pt]{\@mathmargin=#1\@fleqntrue}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother
```

Here there is an optional argument allowing you to set the indent.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fleqns}[1][0pt]{\@mathmargin=#1\@fleqntrue}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  x=y
\end{equation}

\begin{fleqns}
  \begin{equation}
    z=t
  \end{equation}
  text
  \begin{gather}
    p=q\\
    y=r
  \end{gather}
\end{fleqns}

\begin{equation}
  s=t
\end{equation}

\begin{fleqns}[2em]
  \begin{equation}
    z=t
  \end{equation}
  text
  \begin{gather}
    p=q\\
    y=r
  \end{gather}
\end{fleqns}

\end{document}
```

You could extend this to define flushleft versions of the different equationing environments, but that would require a new definition for each case.